generating plot with facet wrap and comparing populations
I have two tables below:
Healthy Control:
df1 <- data.frame(pt="HC",subset1=rnorm(10,20,0.2), subset2=rnorm(10,20,0.2))

Disease:
df2 <- data.frame(pt="Dz",subset1=rnorm(10,10,0.2), subset2=rnorm(10,10,0.2))

I am doing:
full <- rbind(pivot_longer(df1,-pt), pivot_longer(df2,-pt))
ggplot(full, mapping = aes(x = name, y = value, fill=name)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_jitter(shape = 16, position = position_jitter(0.3)) +
  facet_wrap(~pt)


I am hoping to run a t test and compare subset1 and subset2 between the two groups and if the difference is significant, I want to show it on top of the disease graph. similar to this:


library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

gg <- ggviolin(full, x = 'name', y = 'value', fill='name', facet.by='pt') +
   geom_jitter(shape = 16, position = position_jitter(0.3)) +
   theme(legend.position="none")

stat.test <- full %>%
  group_by(pt) %>%
  t_test(value~name)  %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "bonferroni") %>%
  add_significance("p.adj") %>%
  add_xy_position(fun = "mean_sd", x = "name") 

gg + stat_pvalue_manual(
  stat.test, label = "p.adj.signif", tip.length = 0.01, y.position=20
) 



df1 <- data.frame(pt="HC", subset1=rnorm(100,10,2), subset2=rnorm(100,7,2))
df2 <- data.frame(pt="DZ", subset1=rnorm(100,10,2), subset2=rnorm(100,10,2))
full <- rbind(pivot_longer(df1,-pt), pivot_longer(df2,-pt))


I use ggpubr, and rstatix libraries to accomplish this.
Here's a useful walkthrough on datanovia : https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-add-p-values-onto-a-grouped-ggplot-using-the-ggpubr-r-package/
When doing this for a faceted plot, add the facet_wrap after the stat_pvalue_manual.
